# Unexpected behaviour in Image Cropping

Tags: android

I'm cropping an image returned by a (default)camera app but the result is a larger-sized file (~4x larger).

```
Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(OrigImagePath);

int width = bitmapOrg.getWidth();
int height = bitmapOrg.getHeight();
int shortLength = (width <= height) ? width : height;

// square proportions
int xOffset = (width - shortLength) / 2;
int yOffset = (height - shortLength) / 2;

Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg, xOffset, yOffset, shortLength, shortLength);

// save
File f = new File(Util.getDir(OrigImagePath) + File.separator + "thumbnail.jpg");

try {
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f);
    resizedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I just found out about the file size discrepancy. No wonder I was getting `OutOfMemoryErrors`. I know I can use the `BitmapFactory.Options inSampleSize` but I really just want to crop the original Image without losing detail. There's clearly something I'm missing here.

Comment: `resizedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);` creates an uncompressed jpeg version of your bitmap

Comment: Does that mean the Original Bitmap is already compressed? I want the result to be the same as the original (just cropping the sides off).

Comment: A Bitmap is, by definition, not compressed. `OrigImagePath`, however, is a compressed image file. When you decode it into a Bitmap, the resulting bitmap is not compressed. When you compress it to `f`, the format you choose is lossless, hence very big.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try this:

```
Bitmap resizedBitmap =  Bitmap.createBitmap (xOffset, yOffset, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
```

instead of this:

```
Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg, xOffset, yOffset, shortLength, shortLength);
```

Hope this helped!